# How can I check if SHIFT is pressed in AUTOLISP?

Tags: autocad-plugin, autolisp

In my AutoLISP code I need to check if [SHIFT] button is pressed. 
In C++ I can do it by `GetKeyState` from `user32.dll`, but how to call it in AutoLISP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun c:mx ()
(if (acet-sys-shift-down)
    (Princ "Shift Key is Down") 
    (Princ "Shift Key is not Down") 
)
(princ)
)
```

Comment: Add some description with your code, how it can help solve the problem.

Comment: (acet-sys-shift-down) that' exacly what I need. thank You